# Есть ли в intelij IDEA наиболее детальная проверка кода?

Tags: intellij-idea, отладка, code-style, code-analyst

Существует ли в *INTELIJ Idea* такой анализ кода, который проверял бы каждую инструкцию и напрямую, строка за строкой, выводил бы (транслировал), все действия, совершающиеся в каждой строке?
Например.

```
while(true) {
  incr++;
}
System.out.println("Finished");
```

Анализ кода вывел бы:

`enter the while loop:
increment incr
increment incr
...`

Теперь понятно, где программа перестает работать корректно.
Это бы помогло распознать, в какой части кода что-то пошло не так.
[image: Получается бесконечный цикл. Но debug об этом ни слова]

Comment: Это называется отладка кода, или дебаг. Погуглите.

Comment: @Ksenia, я добавил скриншот работы дебага. Он работает, но когда входим в бесконечный цикл, он об этом не может догадаться

Comment: Ну, idea интеллектуальная, но не всезнающая) Как правильно заметил @Profesor08, idea автоматически подсвечивает блоки наподобие while(true) желтым цветом, указывая на бесконечный цикл в описании. Но у Вас на скриншоте вместо true указано вычисляемое значение, и если idea не подчеркнула эту строку, значит, компилятор не может знать, будет ли этот цикл бесконечным. Если бы idea была настолько умной, программисты были бы не нужны :)

Comment: Значит опять все своими руками...)  Понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Да есть, запусти программу в дебаг режиме, так у тебя станут доступны дополнительные элементы управления, где ты можешь гулять по программе как угодно.

На сколько я знаю, idea автоматически подсвечивает подобные блоки желтым цветом, указывая на бесконечный цикл в описании. Так-же находит рекурсии, которые тоже могут привести к зависанию.